# MySkillsFuture "claim/gateway" response showing error for "aes-256-cbc" encryption decryption method

Tags: encryption

While testing sfc for uat server it's passing the "https://uat-api.ssg-wsg.sg/skillsFutureCredits/claims/encryptRequests" api successfully and also getting the "claim request" after decryption. And also getting the same success response from "postman" also. But when I submit the post form for "https://uat.sfc.myskillsfuture.gov.sg/sfc2-ind/api/individual/sfcpayment/claim/submit/gateway" containing the claim request often it redirects to the login page but most of the time it's showing an error "**Processing Error Occurred**". When I searched about the error I found that SFC is changing their chipper suits. But their isn't any more information about the using process of these chippers.
I am stuck in this portion from around one month. getting no solutions.

**Tried Encryption Method in php:**

```
$method  = 'aes-256-cbc';   
$key = base64_decode($encryption_key);
$iv  = mb_convert_encoding("SSGAPIInitVector", "UTF-8");           
$ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($plaintext,$method,$key,OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,$iv);  
$encryptedPayload = base64_encode($ciphertext);
```

**Tried encryptRequests api :**

```
$headers = array(
  "Content-Type: text/plain",
);

$url = "https://uat-api.ssg-wsg.sg/skillsFutureCredits/claims/encryptRequests";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $encryptedPayload);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, getcwd() . "key.pem");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, getcwd() . "cert.pem");

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
  if ($resp === false) {
      throw new Exception(curl_error($curl), curl_errno($curl));
  }
  $httpReturnCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($curl);




**Tried Decryption Method in php:**

$data = mb_convert_encoding($resp,"UTF-8");
$decryptedResponse = openssl_decrypt($data,$method,$key,0,$iv);
$decryptedData = json_decode($decryptedResponse);
$claimRequest = $decryptedData->data->claimRequest;




**Tried Post form for "https://uat.sfc.myskillsfuture.gov.sg/sfc2-ind/api/individual/sfcpayment/claim/submit/gateway" :**

<form action="https://uat.sfc.myskillsfuture.gov.sg/sfc2-ind/api/individual/sfcpayment/claim/submit/gateway" method ="post">  
<textarea id="encryptedPayload" name="encryptedPayload" rows="10" cols="100"><?php echo $claimRequest ?></textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit" id="submitSfc" value="Proceed To Claim" style="background-color: blue;color:white;padding:10px;margin-top:10px">
</form>
```

I am expecting to redirect into the "claim/submit/gateway".